# Which part of my website makes it too wide?

Tags: html, css, position

I am having the weirdest problems...

I am having the problem, that the content of my website stretches out to wide. What I mean is, that I am having a horizontal scrollbar. I really don't know why. I checked every single line of my CSS code as well as my HTML. But the problem persists.

I hope someone is bored enough to help me out here...

I uploaded the site to netlify: https://usov.netlify.app/

The HTML

```
<!Doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>UniqueSurvival</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devicewidth, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href="css/gallery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1908996dcd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link rel="icon" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div id="page-container">
        <div id="main-nav">
            <nav>
                <a href="https://docs.uniquesurvival.net/" target="_blank"><i class="fas fa-book"></i> Wiki</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="content-wrap">
            <p id="headline">Unique Survival</p>

            <div id="content-content">
                lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </div>
            
        </div> <!--schließt content wrap-->
        <footer id="footer">
            
        </footer>
    </div> <!--schließt page container-->
    </body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Varela+Round&display=swap');

:root{
    font-family: "Varela Round";
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    background: rgba(37, 37, 38);
    background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0), rgba(37, 37, 38)),
    url('/pics/bg.jpg');
    width: auto;
    height: 114.2%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: white;
}

div#page-container{

}

div#main-nav{
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: "Varela Round";
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10px;
}

    div#main-nav a{
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    div#main-nav a:link{
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
    }
    div#main-nav a:visited {
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: rgb(158, 158, 158);
    }
    div#main-nav a:hover { 
        transition: 0.5s;
        color: rgb(175, 255, 144); 
    }

div#content-wrap{
    width: 60%;
    position: relative;
    left: 20%;
    top: 0;
    text-align: justify;
}

p#headline{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 99%;
    font-size: 6rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.5rem;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#ffffff, rgba(66, 66, 66, 0));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

div#content-content{
    background-color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    position: relative;

}
```

Comment: div#main-nav remove position: relative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `max-width: 80%` under `div#main-nav`.
`left:20%` is pushing the nav 20% out of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Delete "position: relative;" or add "max-width: 80%;"

```css
div#main-nav {
    z-index: 0;
    font-family: "Varela Round";
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    left: 20%;
    top: 10px;
}
```